# Unable to Configure external MySQL Databaser to Owncloud?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, owncloud

Hi I am trying to setup Owncloud with an external MySQL DB.

In MySQL server - I have changed bind-address= 0.0.0.0 , created a user and granted , flushed privileges.

Now i am able to connect to MySQL from CMD in Owncloud server.

When I try to setup getting an error
" Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ‘oc_root2’@’%’ to database ‘owncloud’ "

Can some one please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Nextcloud. This is more actively maintained, fully open source and has more features. Setting up Nextcloud via the command line works fine for me. I suggest that you use the setup-nextcloud.php script and everything should be automatic.

Comment: Will Give a try.